# Quartz Scheduler 1.8.6 is suddenly stopping with Spring 3.0.5 framework in Unix environment without exception

Tags: spring, unix, quartz-scheduler

Quartz Scheduler 1.8.6 is suddenly stopping with Spring 3.0.5 framework in Unix environment without exception.

PFB the global properties file with quartz properties, Scheduler and Job config details:

```
#CMS Scheduler properties

cms.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
cms.org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
cms.org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
cms.org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false
cms.org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
cms.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
cms.org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
cms.org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = false
cms.org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
cms.org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

##Scheduler Timer properties

#DeltaTimeStampTrigger scheduling properties
cms.deltaTimeStampTrigger.startDelay.time.milliseconds=1000
cms.deltaTimeStampTrigger.repeatInterval.time.milliseconds=300000

#DeltaSectionTrigger scheduling properties
cms.deltaSectionTrigger.startDelay.time.milliseconds=1000
cms.deltaSectionTrigger.repeatInterval.time.milliseconds=600000

#EnrollmentsTimeStampTrigger scheduling properties
cms.enrollmentsTimeStampTrigger.startDelay.time.milliseconds=2000
cms.enrollmentsTimeStampTrigger.repeatInterval.time.milliseconds=600000

#EnrollmentsSectionTrigger scheduling properties
cms.enrollmentsSectionTrigger.startDelay.time.milliseconds=2000
cms.enrollmentsSectionTrigger.repeatInterval.time.milliseconds=600000
```

These values are picked by Maven Build and placed in the quartz.properties using templating.

applicationContext

There are 3 more triggers with similar configuration.

It works fine on my local Windows XP machine but when deployed in Unix environment, it stops working after 10-14 hours without throwing any exceptions.

I have also taken thread dump but it does not show any blocked threads.

I have tried by increasing the number of thread-count but that also does not seem to be working for me.

Can anybody please look into this and suggest if I am missing anything.

Comment: Try looking into Quartz debug logs. You will surely find something mishap there.

Comment: How do I look Quartz Debug logs? Do you mean logger.info() statements written in Quartz Jobs in my Spring application log?

Comment: yes ... you will have to keep log4j.properties in your classpath and specific slf4j-log4j.jar too :-)

Comment: @Shinchen: Yes, you are right. After checking the quartz debug logs, I came to know that it was loading quartz 1.6.1 instead of 1.8.6 as mentioned in pom.xml. Actually, it was taking reference of quartz 1.6.1 from some parent pom.xml. So, the main issue was that it was loading both versions of quartz api namely 1.6.1 and 1.8.6 together! Thanks a lot for your help.